# Devise and handling the flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise 3.1.1 with rails 3 and I have this flash handling code in my layout:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :section, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "flash" %>
<% end %>
```

I sign into my app, flash says:

```
"Signed in successfully."
```

then sign out, then sign in incorrectly and flash says:

```
"Signed out successfully."
"Invalid email or password."
```

I think I understand why I am getting two messages, when signing in incorrectly there is no redirect, just a render.

Not sure how to fix it though.

Comment: I think render takes future flash messages and moves them to the current context (as it does with clean redirects). Have you modified your devise controllers? I get a flash message when I sign in incorrectly in my app with pure defaults.

Comment: @farnoy - thanks for the reply. I have not modified my controller, the problem is I am getting the "Signed out successfully." flash when I have entered details in incorrectly.

Comment: Could you verify your translations? Also, think about any unconventional code you write for your models, it always comes up in weird things like this one.

Comment: @farnoy - translations are as expected. Not sure what to look out for in the model, as far as I can tell, I have a bulk standard devise install. Followed Ryan's Railcasts to get it installed.

Comment: pingu, could you show your custom RegistrationsController if any?

Comment: @Billy - I don't have a custom registrations controller.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I figured out the reason.

When you dig into Devise's source of SessionsController, you'll find `#create` method as follows:

```
# POST /resource/sign_in
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

In above code, Devise sets flash message for success signed in here. That's what the message you saw as `"Signed in successfully."`. It uses the method `set_flash_message` which is just a wrapper of `flash[key]= "something"`. The same is true for `#destroy` method which show you `"Signed out successfully"`.

Note in above code, there is **no code to set error message** such as "Invalid password or email". So how comes this message you saw? It is set in `Devise::FailureApp`

```
def recall
  env["PATH_INFO"]  = attempted_path
  flash.now[:alert] = i18n_message(:invalid)
  self.response = recall_app(warden_options[:recall]).call(env)
end
```

Note here, the method is `flash.now`, not `flash`. The difference is `flash.now` will deliver flash message in current request, not next.

> By default, adding values to the flash will make them available to the next request, but sometimes you may want to access those values in the same request. For example, if the create action fails to save a resource and you render the new template directly, that's not going to result in a new request, but you may still want to display a message using the flash. To do this, you can use flash.now in the same way you use the normal flash. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

So the reason is revealed now.

1. You signed out. You hit `SessionsController#destroy`. Devise destroyed your session, brings you to `/users/sign_in`, render `'new` template for your sign in again. The flash object contains the successful signed out message and you saw it.
2. Now you tried to sign in in same page. This time your form submit hit `#create`. If error, Devise will not redirect you to anywhere but render the same `'new'` template again with the `flash.now` object which contains sign in error message.

In step 2, you last flash object is not removed because no new request rendered, but another new `flash.now` object is added. So you see two message.

### Solution

Of course it's possible to override Devise to change this behaviour, but that's troublesome and **unnecessary**.

A more convenient and user-friendly solution is, **do not land the user on sign in page after either signed in or signed out**.

This is easily by setting `store_location` and override `after_sign_in_path_for` and `after_signed_out_path_for` in your application controller.

```
def store_location
  disable_pattern = /\/users/
  session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ disable_pattern
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

By this setting the user will land on his previously browsed page either after signed in or signed out, and they will not see two flash messages in the question again.

The reason is, when the user signed out, he will be redirect to previous page and see the signed out message. When he want to sign in, he need to go to sign in page which is a new request, then the previous signed out flash will be removed.

Comment: Wow, what a fantastic and detailed answer, thanks! For my app, the sign in form exists in a popup, so has to be rendered on every page. I am considering deleting the "signed in" and "signed out" messages, not convinced the user needs to see these. Bounty on its way, I have to wait another 17 hours before awarding apparently.

Comment: @pingu, my pleasure to be of help. For popup sign_in form, the above settings still apply and make more sense since user will go back to the same page. Just forget in the answer that `store_location` should be a `before_filter`, and better to be on pages for display, for example: `before_filter :store_location, only: [:show, :index]`. I suggest to keep these messages as they are useful in my opinion or you can customize it in devise.yml. Anyway if you don't want them, just remove the view code, no need to override Devise. Thanks for your bounty :)

Comment: Great answer, the solution would be to just redirect to a safe path for guests after sign out (safe being not requiring authentication). Good convention is to have `root_url` on main subdomain to not require authentication, then everything just works without `after_sign_out_path_for`