# Remove flash message on refresh of page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using devise for log in and i have overwrite my devise session controller and showing flash messages if user enter wrong information using following code to display flash message.

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :section, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => " flash" %>
<% end %>
```

And it is working fine and showing **"Invalid email or password."** message if user enter wrong email and password .

Now it is still showing the same flash message if i refresh the page.
But i want the flash message to be remove if page gets refresh .please help me on same.

Comment: Don't know with `devise`,but in a normal Rails app if this line `flash[:notice] = "Invalid Email or Password"` is changed to `flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid Email or Password"` then it works.

Comment: Thanks Pavan..but i am looking for devise way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use flash.discard after it getting displayed. Possibly like:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :section, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => " flash" %>
    <% flash.discard(name) %>
<% end %>
```

I haven't tested this, so try if it works.

Comment: Devise sets flash messages as flash[:key] instead of flash.now[:key]. The latter shows flash message only for the current request. Some plausible solution for your problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303878/devise-and-handling-the-flash